# WebClient TimeOut exception c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient, timeoutexception

I have a problem using a WebClient in ASP.NET MVC with c#. I can't call my BackEnd using webclient anymore. It used to work but for some reason now I always get a TimeOut Exception.

The thing is, I can call the webservice from chrome and it works, the same code works in another project, it used to work in my main one, but it doesn't anymore. I checked my previous versions using SourceTree, and it seems I haven't changed any config files.

Any idea on where my problem could come from ?

Comment: If both applications sits on different servers etc then maybe you should speak with DevOps about firewall or anything else can block the request

Comment: try to telnet that IP and Port to see the connectivity. You can also use tracert to check the availability of that service.